# Remove "Multiplayer Unavailable" alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

My app is trying to show the GKMatchRequest screen when the user taps on a button. If the user isn't authenticated by then, an alert is shown (within GameKit) that displays an alert saying "Multiplayer Unavailable – Player is not signed in". I didn't implement this alert view in my code, is there a way to remove it so I can implement my own alert-type view?

Comment: No, you cannot as it is platform specific!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't allow your user to tap the button until your `authenticateHandler` block is called.